# How can I iterate networkx edge data with functions that do not return an edge with key?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, edges

Using a MultiGraph().

Trying to find to use `networkx` functions that iterate over edges but produce only (src, dst) edges without a key and obtain the key inside the loop.

eg: `networkx.dfs_edges()`

Iterates over edges depth-first producing (src, dst) tuples.

The function doesn't accept a `keys=True` argument.

Therefore inside the loop the following has different behaviours:

`g.get_edge_data(edge)`

```
import networkx as nx
# This works with keys
g = nx.MultiGraph()
g.add_edge(1,2)
for edge in g.edges_iter(keys=True):
    print g.get_edge_data(*edge)
```

> {}

```
# This gets the dict with the edge key, as the function doesn't take `keys=True` as arguments.
for edge in nx.dfs_edges(g):
    print g.get_edge_data(*edge)
```

> {0: {}}

Is it possible to iterate similarly with these sort of functions?

In this particular example I would like to be able to `get_edge_data` of a specific edge from an edge given by `dfs_edges`, rather than getting all the dictionaries multi-edges could produce between 2 nodes of a `Multi<Di>Graph`

```
# eg: This works.
for edge in g.edges_iter(keys=True):
    print  g.edge[edge[0]][edge[1]][edge[2]]
```

> {}

```
# But can't do something similar with `dfs_edge` as I lack the key information.
for edge in nx.dfs_edges(g):
    print  g.edge[edge[0]][edge[1]][edge[2]]
```

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  I'm not sure what it is you actually want to do.

Comment: Just checking in again - what do you mean by "iterate similarly with these sort of functions?"  What would you like to do?

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks for your comment, I will add in the question. Basically I want to be able to iterate without inconvenience with the key, with a MultiDiGraph, as easy as with a DiGraph.

Comment: `dfs_edges` only returns those edges that are crossed in a depth first search, so it will only ever return one edge of multiple edges between two nodes.  So there's no reason for it to return a key.

Answer (score 1):

The depth first search will only see the first edge to a given node.  If there are two edges between two nodes (since it's a `MultiGraph`), or even just there are multiple paths through different nodes to the same node, it will only ever return the first edge encountered.

Thus if you have

```
G=nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(1,4)])
G.edges()
> [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
for edge in nx.dfs_edges(G,1): #depth first search starting with node 1.
    print edge
> (1, 2)
> (2, 3)
> (3, 4)
```

It does not return every single edge of the network.  Note for example, `(1,4)` and two of the `(1,2)` edges are not returned.  If we did a depth first search starting at `4`:

```
for edge in nx.dfs_edges(G,4):
    print edge
> (4, 1)
> (1, 2)
> (2, 3)
```

which misses the `(3,4)` and again two of the `(1,2)` edges.

So the reason they didn't include an option for the key of the edge to be returned is because there really isn't a reason that you would want it to return the key.  It's only going to return one of the edges.

From your question, it looks like you are expecting it to iterate through every single edge rather than just the subset of edges crossed in a dfs.  If you can say what your desired output would be for the `G` I've defined, I can try to produce that function.  But for now, you can do

```
for edge in nx.dfs_edges(G):
    edgekeys = G.edge[edge[0]][edge[1]].keys()
    print  G.edge[edge[0]][edge[1]][edgekeys[0]]
```

which just takes the first key from the possible choices.

Comment: Thanks Joel, will try this.

2 comments:

- it's more accurate to say that each edge with more than 1 attribute is shown multiple times.

- it also appears to be that the edge (2,3) is skipped so it's not iterating over all edges?

Comment: Thank you, but I need something that iterates over all edges, so I can update the attributes. If it happened to have an empty one, it would add information in the attribute.  In your eg. for instance it is possible to do `G.get_edge_data(2, 3)` and get an empty `dict`, but as you say, this generator would skip it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Regarding your first comment, that was noted in the question as 'The function doesn't accept a keys=True argument.'

Comment: Regarding comment 2, how did it break?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, if you copy the code I wrote into a terminal, it works (where the comment says it works)

Comment: that is NOT the code that works. The argument keys=True was changed.

The code in the question says:
`for edge in g.edges_iter(keys=True)`

The code you posted is different
`for edge in g.edges_iter(data=True)`

Comment: I'm noting that it is confusing that you state that code that works is actually not working or giving different errors. Perhaps your setup is different, there is no need to use words in italics for describing code that is different from the question. And also a generator that iterates more than once over an item of interest is not useful for the problem in the question.

Comment: The code in the question works. This is literally from the console:

Python 2.7.5
>>> import networkx as nx
# This works
g = nx.MultiGraph()
g.add_edge(1,2)
>>> # This gets the dict with the edge key, as the function doesn't take `keys=True`
for edge in nx.dfs_edges(g):
    print g.get_edge_data(*edge)
{0: {}}
>>> # eg: This works.
for edge in g.edges_iter(keys=True):
    print  g.edge[edge[0]][edge[1]][edge[2]]
{}
more
>>> nx.__version__
'1.8.1'
>>> # This works with keys
for edge in g.edges_iter(keys=True):
    print edge
(1, 2, 0)
>>> 
for edge in g.edges_iter():
    print edge
(1, 2)

Comment: Okay - I understand better what you're doing.  I was assuming you were after the keys associated with the attributes of the edges, rather than the keys associated with the edge itself (since it's a `MultiGraph`).  So I'm editing my answer.